# Capture Camera After 5 seconds

Tags: c#, delay, capture

I am working with a Face Recognition project and I want to create a "Register" method.

Register Method must be able to capture 10 faces with different angles. So, I need to capture 10 different image files, but I need to be 5 seconds after so they would have time to change the angle of their face.

I know how to capture 10 faces continuously, but I can't do it with delay of 5 seconds every next capture.

This is my code for capturing 10 image continuously:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
imgCapture = capture.QueryFrame();
}
```

Comment: Just from a user perspective maybe try 3 seconds instead of 5, both would work but sitting there posing for a minute at a camera probably could get quite timely. Or maybe try less image captures?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a timer with it's interval set to `5000` (5000 milliseconds which is 5 seconds):

```
int Snapshots = 0;

void Timer1_Tick()
{
    imgCapture = capture.QueryFrame();
    x++;
    if (x == 10) Timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: @PeterRitchie, probably no one. That's why I suggested using a timer instead.

Comment: I need to put timer1.start() at my Register Button first right?

Comment: @julianconcepcion, yes. Wherever you want the timer to start (and so the capturing to start). Make sure, though, if you use the timer multiple times to reset `Snapshots` to 0.